# How to make QNetworkReply to return custom data?

Tags: c++, qt

I am going to use QNetworkAccessManager to make requests to HTTP server by my mobile app to the server. The question is, how do you link custom data to each request ? I tried to subclass QNetworkReply but I found out that I have to implement virtual methods `close()` and `isSequential()` but I don't know what those should return so I am afraid I am going to break network request functionality.

For example, when my app does the log in procedure, it has to store the email address of the account:

```
class MyApp : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    QNetworkRequest             request;
    QNetworkReply               *reply;
    QNetworkAccessManager       *manager;

    ...

}

void MyApp::do_log_in(QString email, QString password) {
    QString s;

    someobject.email=email; // <-- I have to store email address before sending request to server, but where do I store it?
    s.append("http://myapp.com/do-auth.php?email=");
    s.append(QUrl::toPercentEncoding(email));
    s.append("&password=");
    s.append(QUrl::toPercentEncoding(password));
    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(login_finished(QNetworkReply*)));
    request.setUrl(QUrl(s));
    manager->get(request);

}

void MyApp::login_finished(QNetworkReply *rep) {
    DepservReply *reply;
    QString email;
    ....
    email= ...... // <-- I need to get the email address from QNetworkReply object somehow
    ///my code here handling server reply
    ....
}
```

So, how do I implement storage and retrieval of email in my case, what classes should I subclass and what methods should I re-implement ?

Comment: There are several approaches, but you can simply return the data in a json structure with the request in the structure. So you don't need to subclass anything. Your network reply processor can simply check the request to see what data is in the rest of the message. I do it like this; I return a json structure with three parts; request, result code, and data. The request tells me which call I made, the result code tells me if it worked and the data contains the results when it did work.

Comment: @johnelemans , what if the server does not respond ? what if the connection is lost in the middle of the call and you have to time it out? That's why it is much better to relate additional data to the request itself.

Comment: In that case you will get a timeout on the request.

Comment: @johnelemans, and what if you connected to the server, the connection is established but there is no response from server (it is busy and can't respond), so you have to abort this call from the app. How do you know which request is it if you have many requests in parallel?

Comment: You can set a timer on each call. If the timer fires, it can identify the call which timed out.

Comment: @johnelemans and how do you link the timer to QNetworkReply object? QNetworkReply object is the only object you receive in your signal, and this object is not created by your code, it is created by QT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can leverage the dynamic property system available in each `QObject` and hold the data in the reply:

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/network-reply-tracking-40707025
#include <QtNetwork>

class MyCtl : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QNetworkAccessManager manager{this};
    // ...
    void reply_finished(QNetworkReply *reply);
public:
    MyCtl(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void do_log_in(const QString &email, const QString &password);
};

static const char kAuthGetSalt[] = "req_auth-get-salt";
static const char kDoAuth[] = "req_do-auth";
static const char kEmail[] = "req_email";
static const char kPassword[] = "req_password";

static const auto authGetSaltUrl = QStringLiteral("https://myapp.com/auth-get-salt.php?email=%1");
static const auto doAuthUrl = QStringLiteral("https://myapp.com/do-auth.php?email=%1&passwordHash=%2");

MyCtl::MyCtl(QObject *parent) : QObject{parent}
{
    connect(&manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &MyCtl::reply_finished);
}

void MyCtl::do_log_in(const QString &email, const QString &password) {
    auto url = authGetSaltUrl.arg(email);
    auto reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest{url});
    reply->setProperty(kAuthGetSalt, true);
    reply->setProperty(kEmail, email);
    reply->setProperty(kPassword, password);
}

void MyCtl::reply_finished(QNetworkReply *reply) {
    if (!reply->property(kAuthGetSalt).isNull()) {
        reply->deleteLater(); // let's not leak the reply
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            auto salt = reply->readAll();
            auto email = reply->property(kEmail).toString();
            auto password = reply->property(kPassword).toString();
            Q_ASSERT(!password.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty());
            QCryptographicHash hasher{QCryptographicHash::Sha1};
            hasher.addData(salt); // the server must hash the same way
            hasher.addData("----");
            hasher.addData(password.toUtf8());
            auto hash = hasher.result().toBase64(QByteArray::Base64UrlEncoding);
            auto url = doAuthUrl.arg(email).arg(QString::fromLatin1(hash));

            auto reply = manager.get(QNetworkRequest{url});
            reply->setProperty(kDoAuth, true);
            reply->setProperty(kEmail, email);
        }
    }
    else if (!reply->property(kDoAuth).isNull()) {
        if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
            auto email = reply->property(kEmail).toString();
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Use a constant for a property name to avoid typos by letting the compiler check that you're using a valid identifier.

The example above rectifies the following critical safety issues in your code:

1. Sending security credentials over a clear connection: use `https://`, not `http://`.
2. Sending a password in cleartext: instead, send a salted hash of it. Your server should generate a random salt for each account when the accounts are created. Existing accounts can be left unsalted, but they should acquire a salt as soon as the user changes the password.

Also note that a `QString` to `QUrl` conversion will automatically percent-encode the string, so doing it explicitly is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

In this case `email` is part of the request's URL so you could just extract it from there (the `QNetworkReply` has access to the `QNetworkRequest` it is handling, see `QNetworkReply::request()`).

You an also store more or less any kind of data as a dynamic property because `QNetworkReply` is a `QObject` derived class, see `QObject::setProperty()`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This is probably the best solution. If I understood correctly I can subclass QNetworkRequest and add email to it as member, then pass the new class as parameter (with a cast) to QNetworkAccessManager::get(), correct? Or just set a dynamic property to QNetworRequest (not QNetworkReply because QNetworkReply is the object you get only after the request is made and not before)

Comment: @Nulik The dynamic properties are really meant exactly for your use case. You don't need to subclass anything. Just use them!

Comment: @Nulik: I don't think subclassing `QNetworkRequest` would work, I expect you would get "slicing" when being stored in the `QNetworkReply`.
I meant that the URL of the request is available and your email is part of the URL's query, which can be retrieved at any time.
But setting a dynamic property would even work for data that is not part of the request/URL

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass QNAM to get more control of it.

network.h

```
class QNAMNetwork : public QNetworkAccessManager
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QNAMNetwork(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~QNAMNetwork();
    inline void insertUserValue(const QString & key, const QString & value){this->m_user_values.insert(key,value);}
    inline QString getUserValue(const QString & key){return this->m_user_values.value(key);}


signals:
    void requestFinished(ExNetwork *, QNetworkReply *);

private slots:
    void _sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, const QList<QSslError> &);
    void _finished(QNetworkReply *);

private:
    QMap<QString, QString>           m_user_values;
 };
```

network.cpp

```
QNAMNetwork::QNAMNetwork(QObject *parent):QNetworkAccessManager(parent)
{
    connect(this, &QNAMNetwork::sslErrors, this, &QNAMNetwork::_sslErrors);
    connect(this, &QNAMNetwork::finished, this, &QNAMNetwork::_finished);
}

QNAMNetwork::~QNAMNetwork()
{
    //qDebug() << __FUNCTION__ << QString::number((long)this,16);
}

void QNAMNetwork::_sslErrors(QNetworkReply * reply, const QList<QSslError> & errors)
{
    reply->ignoreSslErrors(errors);
}

void QNAMNetwork::_finished(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    emit requestFinished(this, reply);
}
```

usecase:

```
QNAMNetwork * network = new QNAMNetwork(this);
network->insertUserValue("email","yourmail@mail.com");
connect(network, SIGNAL(requestFinished(QNAMNetwork*,QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNAMNetwork*,QNetworkReply*)));

QNetworkRequest req(QUrl::fromUserInput(query)); //get url

network->get(req);

...

void YourClass::requestFinished(QNAMNetwork * net, QNetworkReply * rep)
{
   QString email = net->getUserValue("email");
   net->deleteLater();
   rep->deleteLater();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your idea. However QT documentation says that one QNAM object should be enough for the whole application. But if I use your approach with single object, the email will be overwritten by the second call if I send many requests in parallel.